# Encapsulating method call

Tags: c#, .net

I have some mechanics to measure method execution time. Simply at start of method i save time and at end i save time and i compare these two values.

But every time i want to use that i need to alter method body.

I am seeking gor a cleaner way - like to have one object responsible for measuring time which could encapsulate method call - like some wrapper, call that method, pass returned value and in that process also measure time.

Also, i know that it might be a little sci-fi, but is there way to wrap or attach to all methods (or even subset of methods)? It could be used for example also for logging - like "i am calling method of instance XXX with paremeter YYY and returned value vas ZZZ"?

I know something like this was possible in Java EE. (I think it was called interceptors if i remember correctly and they could be attached to some or all methods and add functionality, but i dont know whether is this possible in .net)

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A great way here is to use aspect oriented programming, like PostSharp...and here's the example to use it for time measuring: http://theburningmonk.com/2010/03/aop-method-execution-time-watcher-with-postsharp/

The advantage is, that you just add an attribute to your method and don't have to alter / "contaminate" the method body.

Cheers,
Christian

Answer (score 5):

I used this simple method:

```
TimeSpan TimeAction(Action action)
{
    var sw = new Stopwatch();
    sw.Start();
    action.Invoke();
    sw.Stop();
    return sw.Elapsed;
}
```

And this is how to use it

```
var time = TimeAction(() =>
{
    //your code here    
});
```

Answer (score 4):

I'm using a Stopwatch Wrapper with a IDIsposable interface to measure execution time of methods / code blocks.

```
  public class AutoStopwatch : IDisposable
  {
    private Stopwatch autoStopwatch;
    private String method;
    public AutoStopwatch(String Method)
    {
      this.method = Method;
      autoStopwatch = Stopwatch.StartNew();
    }
    public void Dispose()
    {
      autoStopwatch.Stop();
      Debug.Print(string.Format("Elapsed for {0} : {1}", method, autoStopwatch.Elapsed.ToString()));
    }
  }
}
```

// example

```
 using (AutoStopwatch Awatch = new AutoStopwatch("Read Keys from REDIS"))
            {
              //  Your Stuff
            }:
```

Comment: I admire your creativity, but the solution is abusing a well defined pattern: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dispose_pattern

Comment: Its clean to read, easy to maintain and doesn't clutter code that matters. Thats important to me.

Answer (score 0):

PostSharp Aspects may help you, have a look at the samples on their Features page:

http://www.sharpcrafters.com/postsharp/features